# Eclipse run configuration to run remotely using a script

Tags: java, eclipse

I would like to use a run configuration (or something similar) to run a class from Eclipse using a shell script. The shell script will do a bunch of fancy stuff to make the job run on a machine with more memory. That part I can do.

What I don't know is how to make Eclipse pass the class name and class path to a shell script - and ideally show the output of the shell script in the console window. This seems like it should be simple. I'm using 3.5.2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of a clever way to pass your classpath to your script, but the External Tools Configurations can do this. And the output will be printed in your console. There are *Variables* that can be set up to manage your classpath a bit better than I have done below. Though I've used the working directory as my classes folder, so I only need to use `.` as my classpath.

Variables can be used throughout to set up common paths etc.

[image]